# Update UILabel in for loop - Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uilabel

I am trying to update a `UILabel` text value from within a for loop. It is a counter showing how many files have been processed. The value updates sporadically, but I wish it to be a continuous count.

I understand that this needs to happen on the main thread and I have made sure to dispatch the method call to the main thread.

I am updating the `UILabel` as follows:

```
self.labelSubtitle.text = lSubs
```

Where `lSubs` is a `NSString` holding the file count and some other text.

Before I try and set the `UILabel` I am checking if I am running on the main thread using `[NSThread isMainThread]` which it is. Also adding a breakpoint and running *lldb thread info* shows that it is running on the main thread.

In the same breakpoint I can also see that the _content value for the label in Xcode is what I want it to be and logging the `UILabel` also shows the same. But it isn't being reflected in the app UI on device.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include relevant code.

Comment: @David First of all post your code to get faster help. Second I think you are doing to much processing on the main thread (processing files) that has to be done on background thread.

Comment: SHOW ME THE MONEY! SHOW ME THE CODE!!